# .NET 4 IIS Application crashing randomly - The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP

Tags: .net, iis, clr

been a while since we got this error but we are running out of ideas apart from getting the dump analyzed, thing that we are currently doing. Wondering if some of you already got this issue sorted.

Basically IIS .NET 4.6 app is crashing randomly. We thing must be same issue as this KB explains https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2640103 but the Fix is intended for 4.0 version of .NET.

This is the error  we are getting that is basically the same as old version does.

`Application: w3wp.exe
    Framework Version: v4.0.30319
    Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 00007FF91E450A7B (00007FF91E290000) with exit code 80131506.`

and

`Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x5215df96
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.6.1085.0, time stamp: 0x57a4fd94
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000001c0a7b
Faulting process id: 0x27fc0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d24fff8683eab9
Faulting application path: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 64e7d16b-bc6a-11e6-80c7-000d3ab1ca59
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:`

and

`A process serving application pool 'XXXXXX' suffered a fatal communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The process id was '163776'. The data field contains the error number.`

Any suggestions? We are currently wiaitng on the process to fail again and analyze the dump....

Comment: good question for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: I think the article is referring to the .net CLR which is still 4 for asp.net 4.6 so probably still applies to your case.

Comment: Will have a look at that David, good point.